# In Python, is there an easy way to manipulate dataframe in this way?

Tags: python, data-manipulation

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Hello, I have a dataframe that looks like 1 and would like to make it to 2. What would be the easiest way to do this in Python? Thank you

Comment: Site guidelines require that you show your attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: it looks like some `pivot` or `reshape` - so search these two words in `Google` (together with word `pandas`)

Comment: the easier way to get answer is to put example data as text (as DataFrame) which we can simply copy and use in solution. When you put data as image then you may forget about answer. It is easier to downvote it and close question.

Comment: You may also be looking for ```melt```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for-loop to work with every column separatelly and later add this to new DataFrame

First get columns `Code`, `State1_data`,
Next get string `State1` from string `State1_data` and create column `State` with this value.
Next rename column `State1_data` to `data`.
Finally `append` this to new `DataFrame`.

And repeate it for other colums.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Code': [1,2,3],
    'State1_data': ['A','B','C'], 
    'State2_data': ['D','E','F'], 
    'State3_data': ['G','H','I'],
} # columns

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

# create new DataFrame for result
new_df = pd.DataFrame()

# get names which start with `State`
#columns = ['State1_data', 'State2_data', 'State3_data']
columns = [name for name in df.columns if name.startswith('State')]

for col in columns:
    # get columns `Code`, `State1_data`
    temp_df = df[['Code', col]].copy()  

    # add value `State1` to column `State`
    temp_df['State'] = col.split('_')[0]            

    # rename `State1_data` to `data`
    temp_df = temp_df.rename(columns={col: 'data'})

    # append to new DataFrame
    new_df = new_df.append(temp_df)

# ---     

# change order
new_df = new_df[ ['Code', 'State', 'data'] ]  

# reset index
new_df = new_df.reset_index(drop=True)

print(new_df)
```

Result:

```
   Code State1_data State2_data State3_data
0     1           A           D           G
1     2           B           E           H
2     3           C           F           I
   Code   State data
0     1  State1    A
1     2  State1    B
2     3  State1    C
3     1  State2    D
4     2  State2    E
5     3  State2    F
6     1  State3    G
7     2  State3    H
8     3  State3    I
```

---

**EDIT:**

Now I see you use `Code` as index - so it needs little changes

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Code': [1,2,3],
    'State1_data': ['A','B','C'], 
    'State2_data': ['D','E','F'], 
    'State3_data': ['G','H','I'],
} # columns

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.index = df['Code']
del df['Code']
print(df)

# create new DataFrame for result
new_df = pd.DataFrame()

# get names which start with `State`
#columns = ['State1_data', 'State2_data', 'State3_data']
#columns = [name for name in df.columns if name.startswith('State')]
columns = df.columns

for col in columns:
    # get columns `Code`, `State1_data`
    temp_df = df[[col]].copy()  

    # add value `State1` to column `State`
    temp_df['State'] = col.split('_')[0]            

    # rename `State1_data` to `data`
    temp_df = temp_df.rename(columns={col: 'data'})

    # append to new DataFrame
    new_df = new_df.append(temp_df)
    
# ---

# change order
new_df = new_df[ ['State', 'data'] ]  

print(new_df)
```

Result:

```
     State1_data State2_data State3_data
Code                                    
1              A           D           G
2              B           E           H
3              C           F           I
       State data
Code             
1     State1    A
2     State1    B
3     State1    C
1     State2    D
2     State2    E
3     State2    F
1     State3    G
2     State3    H
3     State3    I
```